# Post to the users Facebook wall from an iOS app

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios4

I know this has been asked a lot here, but none of the answers seem to work for me :(
I'm trying to post text to the users Facebook wall from my iPhone app. I already have the Facebook delveloper stuff set up, and almost everything is working. Almost.

```
facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"123813234381280"];

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
    && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
    facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
}
if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    NSArray* permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              @"publish_stream", nil] retain];

    [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
}

 NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"123813234381280", @"app_id",
                               @"http://test.com/", @"link",
                               @"Test-Name", @"name",
                               //@"Reference Documentation", @"caption",
                               @"Download the app NOW from the App Store", @"description",
                               @"Test-Message",  @"message",
                               nil];


[facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

Now there appears a dialog, but the textfield where it should say "Test-Message" in it is empty. You know, the one where it says what to post on the wall. Everything else works, the description, the link, the name. Everything besides the message.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook is now ignoring the message parameter:

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/510/

> message : This field will be ignored on July 12, 2011 The message to
>   prefill the text field that the user will type in. To be compliant
>   with Facebook Platform Policies, your application may only set this
>   field if the user manually generated the content earlier in the
>   workflow. Most applications should not set this.